# Accessing Data Members after using expand in Odata

Tags: odata, sapui5

I currently have an odata service with 2 entity sets. I am using expand to navigate to second entity set, and binding values from both in a table.

However, I am unable to bind data from second entity set as **{to_PurchaseOrderItem/PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit}**

Am I doing this wrong?

The JSON reply looks something like this, so I am really confused what I am doing wrong.

```
"d": {
    "results": [
      {

        "PurchaseOrder": "4500000001",
        "Language": "EN",
        "PaymentTerms": "0004",
        "CashDiscount1Days": "0",
        "CashDiscount2Days": "0",
        "NetPaymentDays": "0",
        "CashDiscount1Percent": "0.000",
        "CashDiscount2Percent": "0.000",
        "PurchasingOrganization": "1710",
        "PurchasingDocumentOrigin": "9",
        "PurchasingGroup": "001",
        "CompanyCode": "1710",
        "PurchaseOrderDate": "/Date(1468454400000)/",
        "DocumentCurrency": "USD",
        "ExchangeRate": "1.00000",
        "ValidityStartDate": null,
        "ValidityEndDate": null,
        "SupplierQuotationExternalID": "",
        "SupplierRespSalesPersonName": "",
        "SupplierPhoneNumber": "",
        "SupplyingSupplier": "",
        "SupplyingPlant": "",
        "PurchaseOrderType": "NB",
        "IncotermsClassification": "",
        "InvoicingParty": "17300001",
        "ReleaseIsNotCompleted": false,
        "PurchasingCompletenessStatus": false,
        "IncotermsVersion": "",
        "IncotermsLocation1": "",
        "IncotermsLocation2": "",
        "ManualSupplierAddressID": "",
        "AddressCityName": "",
        "AddressFaxNumber": "",
        "PurchasingDocumentDeletionCode": "",
        "AddressHouseNumber": "",
        "AddressName": "",
        "AddressPostalCode": "",
        "AddressStreetName": "",
        "AddressPhoneNumber": "",
        "AddressRegion": "",
        "AddressCountry": "",
        "AddressCorrespondenceLanguage": "",
        "PurchasingProcessingStatus": "02",
        "CreatedByUser": "CB9980000025",
        "CreationDate": "/Date(1468454400000)/",
        "Supplier": "17300001",
        "PurchaseOrderSubtype": "",
        "to_PurchaseOrderItem": {
          "results": [
            {

              "PurchaseOrder": "4500000001",
              "OrderQuantity": "100",
              "PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit": "ES",
              "OrderPriceUnit": "ES",
              "OrderPriceUnitToOrderUnitNmrtr": "1",
              "OrdPriceUnitToOrderUnitDnmntr": "1",
              "NetPriceAmount": "0.21",
              "DocumentCurrency": "USD",
              "NetPriceQuantity": "1",
              "TaxCode": "",
              "PriceIsToBePrinted": true,
              "PurchaseOrderItem": "1",
              "OverdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": "10.0",
              "UnlimitedOverdeliveryIsAllowed": false,
              "UnderdelivTolrtdLmtRatioInPct": "10.0",
              "ValuationType": "",
              "IsCompletelyDelivered": false,
              "IsFinallyInvoiced": false,
              "PurchaseOrderItemCategory": "0",
              "AccountAssignmentCategory": "",
              "MultipleAcctAssgmtDistribution": "",
              "PartialInvoiceDistribution": "",
              "PurchasingDocumentDeletionCode": "L",
              "GoodsReceiptIsExpected": true,
              "GoodsReceiptIsNonValuated": false,
              "InvoiceIsExpected": true,
              "InvoiceIsGoodsReceiptBased": false,
              "PurchaseContract": "",
              "PurchaseContractItem": "0",
              "Customer": "",
              "ItemNetWeight": "0.000",
              "ItemWeightUnit": "",
              "TaxJurisdiction": "0508525201",
              "PurchaseOrderItemText": "RAW15,PD",
              "PricingDateControl": "",
              "ItemVolume": "0.000",
              "ItemVolumeUnit": "",
              "SupplierConfirmationControlKey": "",
              "IncotermsClassification": "EXW",
              "IncotermsTransferLocation": "VENDOR",
              "EvaldRcptSettlmtIsAllowed": false,
              "PurchaseRequisition": "",
              "PurchaseRequisitionItem": "0",
              "IsReturnsItem": false,
              "Plant": "1710",
              "RequisitionerName": "",
              "ServicePackage": "0",
              "EarmarkedFunds": "",
              "EarmarkedFundsItem": "0",
              "IncotermsLocation1": "VENDOR",
              "IncotermsLocation2": "",
              "Material": "RM15",
              "ManufacturerMaterial": "RM15",
              "ServicePerformer": "",
              "ProductType": "1",
              "StorageLocation": "",
              "DeliveryAddressID": "",
              "DeliveryAddressName": "",
              "DeliveryAddressStreetName": "",
              "DeliveryAddressHouseNumber": "",
              "DeliveryAddressCityName": "",
              "DeliveryAddressPostalCode": "",
              "DeliveryAddressRegion": "",
              "DeliveryAddressCountry": "",
              "MaterialGroup": "L002",
              "PurchasingInfoRecord": "5300000201",
              "SupplierMaterialNumber": ""
```

I am trying to access Order Quantity to be specific.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to bind the table itmes first, and then bind to the UOM relatively.

Comment: I got the issue. It was happening because of 1:N maping, and not 1:1. Hence the result set is more like Aggregation withing Aggregation, and this worked fine when I used Master Detail instead of my own UI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing "results" while binding the control. Please see below and try

**{to_PurchaseOrderItem/results/0/PurchaseOrderQuantityUnit}**

Comment: I think you are trying to do property binding on a control. If you are trying to aggregation binding then this will not work.

Comment: Also results is appaearing only if I use $format=json. But it's not there in OData response if I open it via browser.